# Windows Phone 7: How to create a picture album for depositing images from app?

Tags: image, windows-phone-7, xna

I've received requests from my app's users to save images loaded by the app (comic book covers from my remote server) in the local device's picture albums so that they can set the images as lockscreen wallpaper on their device.

In [Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254848.aspx), I see [the SavePicture method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx), but it only takes an image name and the image contents as arguments. Ideally, I would like to be able to define an app-specific album and deposit the images there.

Has anyone had any luck doing this, or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the current SDK, you can only save to the `Saved Pictures` album or the `Camera Roll` album. There's no way to create your an app-specific album at the moment.